# Can Zombies wound when a Hero rolls doubles?

Tags: last-night-on-earth

I was playing Last Night on Earth the other day with some friends and came across a question that I don't believe is clear in the rules.

When a Hero fights a zombie (or the other way around), the hero can only be wounded if the zombie's fight die is tied or higher than the highest hero's fight dice.  What if the hero rolls doubles though?  For example, the hero could roll two 1's, but the zombie rolls a 6.  In that situation, does the hero get wounded?  Or is the zombie considered killed before the hero can be wounded?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Hero gets wounded. In your example, the Zombie rolled a '6', and Zombies win on ties. The Hero must have a higher die for the Zombie to not win. If the Hero has a higher die, but no doubles then the Zombie is **Fended Off**. The Zombie is only wounded if the hero has a higher roll **and** has rolled doubles on any of their Fight Dice. From the [rule book](http://www.flyingfrog.net/lastnightonearth/pdf/LNOE_Rulebook_web.pdf) (page 15).

> **Resolving the Fight** - A Fight is only resolved after all players have decided not to use any more cards or abilities. Once both players have chosen their highest Fight Dice roll and are done using cards and abilities, the fight is resolved as follows:
>
> If the Zombie wins (has a higher die or is tied for highest), the Hero takes one Wound.
>
> If the Hero has a higher roll, the Zombie is *Fended Off*. The fight ends and both the Hero and Zombie remain in the space, unaffected.
>
> If the Hero has a higher roll and has rolled doubles on ANY of the Fight Dice (two 5's for instance), the Zombie takes one Wound (removing it from the board).